# How to make a dictionary in Latex

Tags: latex

I want to have latex commands of this kind:

\setdictionary{dictionary_name}{key}{value}

\getdictionary{dictionary_name}{key}

These commands should do the same as map<string, string> in C++.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Can you explain what you want these macros to do?

Comment: If you want to have an associative container to retrieve values associated with a key, there are several packages. Have a look at pgfkeys. There are also functions in the latex3 bundle as l3keys and l3prop that can solve your problem. texdoc pgfkeys or interface3 to get a description .

Comment: Alain Merigot, Thank you so much. The «pgfkeys» package is exactly what I wanted. Absolutely correct. And thank you so much again.

PS: How do I mark Your answer as solve of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define an associative container, there are several tools. The oldest is the keyval package, that is somehow superseded by more recent packages as pgfkeys and l3keys from LaTeX3.

l3keys and pgfkeys are initially developed as a mean to pass parameters to a macro in the form `key=value`. l3keys is the user interface and should be used with l3prop that implements property lists that can be associated to an object and retrieved. It is also possible to use directly l3prop, if one does not need the `key=value` syntax.

pgfkeys is probably simpler to use. You can define keys in a hierarchical way, set values of theses keys and retrieve it.

Basic use with pgfkeys and l3 is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\begin{document}
% pgfkeys version
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my dictionary/my entry1}{Hello world!}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/my dictionary/my entry1}

% with latex3 prop
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \mydict    % define a container (property list)
\prop_new:N \myotherdict % and another one
\NewDocumentCommand \AddToDict { O{\mydict} m m } % add a key to a dictionary default to \mydict
{
  \prop_put:Nnn #1 {#2}{#3}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \GetFromDict { O{\mydict} m } % get a key from a dictionary default \mydict
{
  \prop_item:Nn #1 {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddToDict{my entry1}{Hello again world!}
\GetFromDict{my entry1}

\AddToDict[\myotherdict]{my entry1}{Hello again again world!}
\GetFromDict[\myotherdict]{my entry1}
\end{document}
```

The LaTeX3 way is a bit more complex as the bundle only contains low level library routines. But it may be more flexible. Look at l3prop entry in the interface3 manual.

With pgfkeys, there many ways to enter values, retrieve them, set default values, associate code to a key, etc. Look at 'key management' in the tikz manual.

Comment: You can also have a key=value interface with `l3prop` in a very simple way: `\NewDocumentCommand\AddToDict { O{\mydict} m } { \prop_put_from_keyval:Nn #1 {#2} }`.